# develop java application on Microsoft Windows Mobile 6.5.3 Professional

Tags: java, eclipse, windows-mobile

I am totally new in Microsoft Windows Mobile 6.5.3 Professional. I an a java developer. I develop application for Android Phone but new in Windows Mobile. So please give the information how this is possible.

What is the SDK for this OS.

How I configure my Eclipse for this.

how I get the Emulator?

I must need to know C++ ?

Where I get the tutorials from the starting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as an IDE goes you cannot use VS 2010 for WM6. VS2010 only works on WM7. You have to use VS2005 Standard or up or VS2008 Pro or up.

Comment: but only I know the name of visual studio, I never use this.
Can I develop application on Java in Eclipse ?

Comment: Some WM6 devices shipped with Esmertec JBed, a JVM for WM6. If this is installed on the device you can probably get a java application running on it. http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=407667

Answer (score 0):

Being a Microsoft platform it uses .net. While there are a few differences between c# and Java, it is nothing a competent developer cannot overcome.

Following is an article on getting started.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb158522.aspx